# Disable shadow in Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way to disable the shadow in Ace Editor when the user's cursor goes past the edge of the view? It also appears when the horizontal scroller is scrolled to the right edge and there is not enough room.

Answer (score 0):

disable it with css

```
.ace_scroller.ace_scroll-left {
    box-shadow: initial!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this shadow
[image]

Comming from .ace_scroller class
[image]

On the react component populating the highlightActiveLine prop to false makes it dissapear
[image]
[image]